# Why is my PHP server redirecting to the wrong address?

Tags: php-fpm, openbsd

I'm setting up a PHP web server on OpenBSD.  `phpinfo()` is up and running.

But, every time I try to install Wordpress, it's redirecting the client to the dummy hostname created on OS install (`mycomputer.my.domain`), which obviously doesn't load.

I've changed the hostname to localhost in `/etc/myname` and restarted the system. Typing in hostname gets me `localhost`.

`phpinfo()` shows:

```
System OpenBSD localhost 5.5 GENERIC#276 i386 
Hostname:Port localhost:80 
_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]  80
_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]  127.0.0.1
_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]  HTTP/1.1
_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]  Hiawatha v9.2
_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]  0.0.0.0
_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"]  200
_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]    192.168.1.102
```

I've tried on both Hiawatha and Apache with the same results.

Where is Wordpress still pulling `mycomputer.my.domain` from and how do I get it to stop?

Comment: See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Is this happening just for wordpress? Or does it redirect you for any html/php file?

Comment: Only Wordpress.  I can load any html file fine and test.php with echo "hello world" also works fine.  Wordpress must be calling some kind of function which is returning mycomputer.my.domain to it.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress hard-codes the site URL within its code, so you will need to change it there.

From [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL), you can add these lines in your site's `wp-config.php` file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://mycomputer.my.domain');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://mycomputer.my.domain');
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a fresh install of Wordpress so there is no existing wp-config.  I have also already tried hardcoding my IP into wp-config.  The installer still insists on trying to go to mycomputer.my.domain (and is ignoring my wp-config entries).